# how can I duplicate venv environment without requirements.txt?

Tags: python-venv

I want to duplicate my environment. I cannot use conda or other tools in personal reason. I also don't want to use requirements.txt because it takes too long time.

How can I solve this problem?

I just copied and pasted original environment folder: myvenv1 to myvenv2

But if I activate myvenv2, it shows myvenv1's name, like this.

root: > source ./myvenv2/bin/activate

(myvenv1) root: >

Comment: Using `requirements.txt` is probably the fastest and safest solution. -- If it is taking too long, then you might have another issue that might need solving first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `requirements.txt` is probably the fastest and safest solution.

Otherwise, I am not 100% sure but... if you copy a virtual environment, then I think that you need to edit the content of some files. For example the `activate` script which will be in charge of setting the prompt. But note that virtual environments are not designed to be copied, renamed or moved around. Things will break if you are not careful.

Comment: Is there any news to this? The way using `requirements.txt` does not work for me since I always run into non solvable dependencies, if I do it this way.

Comment: @gernophil Feel free to ask your own question with your own specific case. Maybe you can tell pip to install what's listed in `requirements.txt` without trying to solve dependencies, by using the [*`--no-deps`*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps) flag. For example: `python -m pip install --no-deps --requirement requirements.txt`.